# Lstm for multivariate sequence prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am confused with my Stacked LSTM model.
Lstm has different type of applications.
For example, in the image, two types of LSTM are shown, machine translation and video classification.

[image]

My model is as follow.

```
def create_stack_lstm_model(units):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
    model.add(LSTM(units, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(n_features))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')  
    return model
stack_lstm_model = create_stack_lstm_model(100)
def fit_model(model):
    early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = 10)
    #history = model.fit(x,y,epochs = 200,validation_split = 0.2,batch_size = 1,shuffle = False,callbacks = [early_stop])
    history = model.fit(x,y,epochs = 250)
    return history
history_gru = fit_model(stack_lstm_model)
```

Input **x has shape (1269, 4, 7)**.
A few samples of input x and output y are as follows.

```
[[ 6 11 14 15 28 45 35]
 [ 2 18 19 21 39 45 36]
 [22 32 41 42 43 44 31]
 [ 5 12 17 18 38 40 22]] [ 5 10 25 27 36 39 40]
[[ 2 18 19 21 39 45 36]
 [22 32 41 42 43 44 31]
 [ 5 12 17 18 38 40 22]
 [ 5 10 25 27 36 39 40]] [ 5 13 25 27 40 44  2]
[[22 32 41 42 43 44 31]
 [ 5 12 17 18 38 40 22]
 [ 5 10 25 27 36 39 40]
 [ 5 13 25 27 40 44  2]] [ 2  5  9 20 21 42 15]
[[ 5 12 17 18 38 40 22]
 [ 5 10 25 27 36 39 40]
 [ 5 13 25 27 40 44  2]
 [ 2  5  9 20 21 42 15]] [ 4 16 21 26 31 37 24]
```

Does this implementation fall into machine translation or video classification?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Sorry I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It falls into the second category (video classification) because  the length of your input equals to the length of output.

The first category assumes that you create a separate LSTM encoder and LSTM decoder. As a result it is possible that output and input sequences have different lengths.